# Python cloud hosting other than Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hosting

What options exist for Python Cloud Hosting other than Google App Engine?

I'm looking for solutions that let me write and publish code to servers that will scale up automatically to meet demand. I don't want to spend my time on IT tasks.

So far, I've really only found this: https://www.picloud.com/

App Engine is great, but has some immaturity limitations such as lack of https support.

Comment: App Engine supports HTTPS just fine - or are you referring to supporting it on your own domain? That's on the roadmap, and there are good reasons why it wasn't available right off the bat.

Comment: Hey, picloud looks pretty cool. And unlike GAE, it supports numpy/scipy!

Comment: Nick, I'm referring to HTTPS support for my own domain. I realize that it works with the appspot domain, but I'd much prefer to launch the product under the company domain. I consider myself a big fan of App Engine, but without HTTPS support, it's just not a viable option.

Answer (score 11):

Google App Engine is a unique cloud platform and you won't find any other similar hosting. Except maybe hosting your own AppScale platform somewhere : http://code.google.com/p/appscale/
But I don't think it's ready yet.

The closest to GAE would likely be some sort of Heroku-clone for Python. I know of two upcoming services :

- http://www.djangy.com
- http://stable.io

You could also try Media Temple Grid Service which has Django grid containers : http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/gs/features/containers.php#django

Answer (score 6):

https://www.dotcloud.com/ might also work for your needs

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for python website / webservice hosting, there are now (a year on from OP) a couple of beta options that look interesting (these may be in production versions by the time this answer is read!)

http://ep.io (any python hosting)
http://gondor.io (django hosting)

these are similar to GAE, but offer traditional back ends - RDBMS (PostGRES).

However picloud and http://www.pythonanywhere.com/ are quite different in that they offer the ability to run and retrieve arbitrary python code in the cloud (no need for an explicit wsgi-built api).

Comment: PythonAnywhere supports WSGI apps too now.

Comment: +1 for PythonAnywhere

Answer (score 4):

How about : http://www.picloud.com/

Comment: He mentioned that one in the question.

Comment: (but it's also an *answer* to his question.  He didn't supply an answer himself, so this is still valid)

Answer (score 3):

You can now use Heroku for Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider something like AppScale or TyphoonAE:

http://code.google.com/p/appscale/

http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/

These are independent and open-source implementations of GAE that can be hosted anywhere you want, and that allow you to get around some of the issues with GAE (e.g. the HTTPS issue you mentioned).

Both support GAE/P but AppScale's Python support is a few versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

Yup..Microsoft Azure:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/

Python is now a 1st class language on Azure.